# Qual è il significato di "diecione"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> La nonna si mordeva le labbra ogni volta che l’episodio le veniva rinfacciato, si riprometteva di pagare il debito del babbo con i suoi risparmi: guadagnava una lira l’ora nei suoi mezzo-servizio. Io giocavo con i miei amici, per la strada, di soldi e **diecioni**: trecento lire era una somma che veniva da ridere a pensarci, tanto mi pareva enorme. Cenavamo, la nonna ed io, a caffè e latte, spendevamo, tutti e due, una lira.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "diecione"? Ho cercato questo vocabolo in parecchi dizionari, ma non l'ho trovato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tratta di una [moneta](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=DIECIONE100):

> nell'uso toscano: moneta da dieci centesimi, più grande del diecino,
>   coniata fino ai primi decenni del XX secolo

Tratto da *[Diario Sentimentale](https://books.google.it/books?id=HZdUTnSCauoC&pg=PT44&lpg=PT44&dq=diecione&source=bl&ots=DqP-zaiSNu&sig=60zeEzt9OrqcQLBluKf4KgD4Z4c&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-jc283LvZAhWOb1AKHTWBAqUQ6AEIRzAI#v=onepage&q=diecione&f=false)* sempre di Vasco Pratolini:

> Ciascun giocatore è fornito di ***diecioni***, i due soldi
>   d'anteguerra, molti dei quali del tempo di re Umberto, affilati
>   dall'uso o, in seguito a magistrali arrotature sulla pietra, lustri e
>   levigati.

Comment: Curioso che non ci sia sui veri dizionari moderni: evidentemente è considerato troppo locale. Aggiungo, dal _Vocabolario italiano della lingua parlata_ di Rigutini e Fanfani (1893), molto toscanocentrico: “Nome che dà il popolo fiorentino alla moneta di rame, del valore di dieci centesimi”.

Comment: Ricordo che fino alla Seconda guerra mondiale una lira era appunto composta da 20 soldi (equivalenti evidentemente a 5 centesimi ognuno).